# Problema com beans no spring : No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring

estou tendo o seguinte problema com os beans no spring:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'agrupamentoTaxonomiaController' defined in file [D:\IBGE\workspaces\Agatha\adaptacao-RedHat-OpenShift\agatha\codigo-fonte\servico\target\classes\br\gov\mpog\gestaoriscos\controller\AgrupamentoTaxonomiaController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.servico.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService]: Error creating bean with name 'agrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\IBGE\workspaces\Agatha\adaptacao-RedHat-OpenShift\agatha\codigo-fonte\servico\target\classes\br\gov\mpog\gestaoriscos\servico\impl\AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'agrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\IBGE\workspaces\Agatha\adaptacao-RedHat-OpenShift\agatha\codigo-fonte\servico\target\classes\br\gov\mpog\gestaoriscos\servico\impl\AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository

```
    package br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio;

    import br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.modelo.AgrupamentoTaxonomia;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    /**
     * Spring Data JPA repository for the AgrupamentoTaxonomia entity.
     */
    public interface AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository extends JpaRepository<AgrupamentoTaxonomia, Long>{
    }
```

AgrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorioImpl

```
@Repository
public class AgrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorioImpl implements AgrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio{

    @Autowired
    private JpaContext jpaContext;

    //RESTO DO CÓDIGO ...
}
```

Alguém saberia me informar como resolver? Aparentemente o @Autowired e os tipos de classe estão definidos e a classe repository também.

**EDIT**

AgrupamentoTaxonomiaController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/agrupamentotaxonomias", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class AgrupamentoTaxonomiaController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgrupamentoTaxonomiaController.class);

    private final AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService service;

    @Autowired
    public AgrupamentoTaxonomiaController(AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    //RESTO DO CÓDIGO...
}
```

AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService

```
/**
 * Service Interface for managing Taxonomia.
 */
public interface AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService {

      //METODOS A SEREM IMPLEMENTADOS EM OUTRA CLASSE
}
```

AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl

```
/**
 * Service Implementation for managing Taxonomia.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl implements AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl.class);

    private final AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository agrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository;

    private final TaxonomiaRepository taxonomiaRepository;

    private final StatusTaxonomiaRepository statusTaxonomiaRepository;

    private final TipoTaxonomiaRepository tipoTaxonomiaRepository;

    private final AgrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio agrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio;

    private final TaxonomiaCustomRepositorio taxonomiaCustomRepositorio;

    private final EventoRepository eventoRepository;

    private final CausaRepository causaRepository;

    private final ConsequenciaRepository consequenciaRepository;

    private final ControleRepository controleRepository;

    private final OrgaoRepository orgaoRepository;

    private final EventoRiscoRepository eventoRiscoRepository;

    private final EventoCausaRepository eventoCausaRepository;

    private final EventoConsequenciaRepository eventoConsequenciaRepository;

    private final ControleEventoRepository controleEventoRepository;

    private final PlanoControleRepository planoControleRepository;

    private final EventoCustomRepositorio eventoCustomRepositorio;

    private final CausaCustomRepositorio causaCustomRepositorio;

    private final ConsequenciaCustomRepositorio consequenciaCustomRepositorio;

    private final ControleCustomRepositorio controleCustomRepositorio;

    private final AgrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper agrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper;

    private final TipoTaxonomiaMapper tipoTaxonomiaMapper;

    private final TaxonomiaMapper taxonomiaMapper;

    private final EventoMapper eventoMapper;

    private final CausaMapper causaMapper;

    private final ConsequenciaMapper consequenciaMapper;

    private final ControleMapper controleMapper;

    @Autowired
    public AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl(AgrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository agrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository, CausaRepository causaRepository, TaxonomiaRepository taxonomiaRepository, StatusTaxonomiaRepository statusTaxonomiaRepository, TipoTaxonomiaRepository tipoTaxonomiaRepository, AgrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio agrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio, TaxonomiaCustomRepositorio taxonomiaCustomRepositorio, ControleCustomRepositorio controleCustomRepositorio, EventoRepository eventoRepository, PlanoControleRepository planoControleRepository, EventoCausaRepository eventoCausaRepository, ConsequenciaRepository consequenciaRepository, AgrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper agrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper, TaxonomiaMapper taxonomiaMapper, ControleRepository controleRepository, EventoCustomRepositorio eventoCustomRepositorio, ConsequenciaCustomRepositorio consequenciaCustomRepositorio, EventoConsequenciaRepository eventoConsequenciaRepository, OrgaoRepository orgaoRepository, ControleEventoRepository controleEventoRepository, EventoRiscoRepository eventoRiscoRepository, CausaCustomRepositorio causaCustomRepositorio, TipoTaxonomiaMapper tipoTaxonomiaMapper, EventoMapper eventoMapper, CausaMapper causaMapper, ConsequenciaMapper consequenciaMapper, ControleMapper controleMapper) {
        this.agrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository = agrupamentoTaxonomiaRepository;
        this.causaRepository = causaRepository;
        this.taxonomiaRepository = taxonomiaRepository;
        this.statusTaxonomiaRepository = statusTaxonomiaRepository;
        this.tipoTaxonomiaRepository = tipoTaxonomiaRepository;
        this.agrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio = agrupamentoTaxonomiaCustomRepositorio;
        this.taxonomiaCustomRepositorio = taxonomiaCustomRepositorio;
        this.controleCustomRepositorio = controleCustomRepositorio;
        this.eventoRepository = eventoRepository;
        this.planoControleRepository = planoControleRepository;
        this.eventoCausaRepository = eventoCausaRepository;
        this.consequenciaRepository = consequenciaRepository;
        this.agrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper = agrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper;
        this.taxonomiaMapper = taxonomiaMapper;
        this.controleRepository = controleRepository;
        this.eventoCustomRepositorio = eventoCustomRepositorio;
        this.consequenciaCustomRepositorio = consequenciaCustomRepositorio;
        this.eventoConsequenciaRepository = eventoConsequenciaRepository;
        this.orgaoRepository = orgaoRepository;
        this.controleEventoRepository = controleEventoRepository;
        this.eventoRiscoRepository = eventoRiscoRepository;
        this.causaCustomRepositorio = causaCustomRepositorio;
        this.tipoTaxonomiaMapper = tipoTaxonomiaMapper;
        this.eventoMapper = eventoMapper;
        this.causaMapper = causaMapper;
        this.consequenciaMapper = consequenciaMapper;
        this.controleMapper = controleMapper;
    }
    //resto do código

}
```

Eu postei só o básico que não mostre as regras de negócio pois é um software da empresa.

Comment: Posta o código do seu controller `agrupamentoTaxonomiaController` e `AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os Mappers da aplicação estavam no construtor e a anotação @Autowired tentava injeta-las como dependências. Isso estava causando o problema, após tira-los do construtor de cada classe a aplicação funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a seguinte anotação na classe principal:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.repositorio");
```

Comment: Não funcionou. :/

Comment: @PedroTeixeira atualizei a resposta

Comment: Ainda não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Service Interface for managing Taxonomia.
 */
@Service
public interface AgrupamentoTaxonomiaService {

      //METODOS A SEREM IMPLEMENTADOS EM OUTRA CLASSE
}
```

Tente realizer a inserçao do @Service na Interface se estiver referenciando ela no seu Controller.

Comment: Já está no AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl que coloquei agora ali em cima.

Comment: @PedroTeixeira pq exatamente esta criando uma implementaçao para o repository?

Comment: Esse projeto é da empresa. Não sei quem fez, me pediram pra alterar o mínimo possível. Também não sei qual foi a finalidade, acreditava ser algum design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

O que pode estar acontecendo é que quando a controller tenta instanciar a classe `AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl` ele não consegue pois só existe um método construtor nessa classe, que necessita a passagem de parametros. O que pode solucionar o seu problema é apagar o construtor da classe `AgrupamentoTaxonomiaServiceImpl` e colocar o `@Autowired` em cima de cada atributo da classe para ser feita a injeção de dependencia.

Comment: Continua dando erro, mas mudou o final dele: 

`No qualifying bean of type [br.gov.mpog.gestaoriscos.servico.mapper.AgrupamentoTaxonomiaMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: tente marcar essa classe com `@Component`, ou crie um `bean` pra ela.